# What is "vaccinium corymbosum" in Esperanto?

Tags: translation

Kio estas “Vaccinium corymbosum” (Amerikanische Heidelbeere ) en esperanto?

Answer (score 5):

I would call them *mirteloj* - and if there was a need to specify what kind, you can clarify it in different ways. *Usona mirtelo, sovaĝa mirtelo, grapolaj mirteloj, ktp.*

Revo suggests *vakcinio* which in my opinion is too broad.

Comment: Eble, "blua vakcinio" estas bonaj vortoj.

Comment: Mi kredas ke ne. Mi kredas ke jam estas kutime nomi la bluajn berojn "mirteloj."